# how to change css to show two products in mobile mode?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

how to change css to show two products in mobile mode?
my website is designed with wordpress CMS and the theme is aloshop and i use 7up-theme plugin to show the bestselling and the newest and the most popular products . but when is mobile mode only one product is shown per column.how can i change it to show two products per column in mobile mode?

my web site url is -> [URL](http://almahdionline.ir)

i tried CSS below:

```css
@media(max-width:960px){
 .tab-content {
  width:50%;
  float:left; 
  }
  }
```

Comment: Which section of the homepage do you want 2 products to be shown side-by-side? There are several product sections on that page.

Comment: there are 4 products under the auto slide show
 
but only one of them is shown per column in mobile mode .

Answer (score 0):

Change your js like this

```
 var owl = $("#owl-demo");

 owl.owlCarousel({
  items : 10, //10 items above 1000px browser width
  itemsDesktop : [1000,4], //4 items between 1000px and 901px
  itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3], // betweem 900px and 601px
  itemsTablet: [600,2], //2 items between 600 and 0
  itemsMobile : false // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option
});
```

Reference : http://www.landmarkmlp.com/js-plugin/owl.carousel/demos/custom.html

Comment: I'm sure there is a problem with CSS . the plugin that is used is 7UP- sv product tab for this section.

Comment: Okay no worries i have seen `owl.carousel' in your source code and the slider using there is `owl` slider so i'm thinking its the effect of `owl-slider`